# Ayuda con expresion regular para validar matriculas de coche

Tags: java, regex

necesito una expresion regular para validar que la matricula de un coche no pueda haber CH o LL

`^[0-9]{1,4}[BCDFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]{3}` esta parte me comprueba que tenga entre 1 y 4 caracteres y 3 letras.

He probado con esta, para excluir CH y LL, pero me deja de fucionar lo anterior `^[0-9]{1,4}([BCDFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][^CH][^LL]){3}`.

Espero que me podais ayudar.
Gracias.
Un saludo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares tienen un patrón conocido como [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), en criollo, permite validar un patrón si hacia adelante encontramos otro. En este caso usaremos un [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) negativo, es decir, validaremos las letras solo si no encontramos las cadenas  `LL` o `CH`. esto último se construye así: `(?!.*(LL|CH))` por lo que el patrón final quedaría:
Este patrón:

```
^[0-9]{1,4}(?!.*(LL|CH))[BCDFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]{3}
```

[Ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/tTsZtI/1)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Patricio, la he probado y funciona a la perfección.